# Methods of dissolving a gas into a liquid

Tags: experimental-chemistry, solutions

I know that carbon dioxide is dissolved into water in a soda fountain using a sort of a tubular manifold that mixes the water with pressurized carbon dioxide as it goes through it.

Is that the best way to dissolve a gas like carbon dioxide into cold (refrigerated) water, or are there better methods? Is there an official name for this kind of device, "aspirator," maybe? How is this done in the lab?

Comment: Have you heard of Condensation?